# Best practices on lowering latency between two endpoints

Tags: ping, internet, latency

I would like to know what tools or what kind of calculation should be made in order to find the lower latency possible between two points physically distant.

For example:

- Ping time from Europe to South America is 300ms
- Ping time from USA to South America is 120ms.
- Ping time from Europe to USA is 150ms.

Should I try to bridge the connection via USA to gain 30ms? or this idea in completely invalid?

How do I find the best path possible between two points?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have control of the fiber and all of the routers along the path, there's not a thing you can do.

Additionally, unless you run your own transit network, you have no control over what path your packets take from point A to point B.

Comment: it is not so hard o route your own packets, though. Rent some servers, set up vpn, there you go.